# "could not find class com.google.android.gms.maps.Supportmapfragment" google map api android in Eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I want to add google map api on my app. But there is a

> could not find class com.google.android.gms.maps.Supportmapfragment

error and I cant find a solution. I skimed other questions from stackoverflow. However they are not correct solution for my problem.
here is my codes:

Map.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import  com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap googleHarita;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
     if (googleHarita == null) {
            googleHarita = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.haritafragment))
                    .getMap();
            if (googleHarita != null) {
                //İstanbul, Kız Kulesi olsun.
                LatLng istanbulKoordinat = new LatLng(41.021161,29.004065);
                googleHarita.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(istanbulKoordinat).title("Kız Kulesi"));
                googleHarita.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(istanbulKoordinat, 13));         
            }
        }

}
```

map.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mimarasistan.Map" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/haritafragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"  />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mimarasistan.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->


    <!-- Cihazdan Google Servislerine erişmek için izin -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mimarasistan.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_api_key" />
          </application>
          </manifest>
```

I also added google play service lib. I didnt understand reason of error. Please help! Thanks

Comment: post the text of Exception, please and clarify which version of Google Play Services do you use

Comment: Sorry! I dont know which one. how can i learn it?

Comment: you have an <meta-data> block in your manifest file, there is "@integer/google_play_services_version" - you can click on it and get.
As you're using Eclipse, I can't help with that problem, but change the Question to indicate that you got error in Eclipse

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse :(  thank you so much for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the way you added google-play-services to your project:

Read the first 3 steps of this blog post I wrote to get an idea of how to do it correctly:

Google Maps API V2

In short, you should import google-play-services as a project in your workspace. and then reference it from your project.

[image]

Comment: I already import the google-play-services as a project in my workspace. But I still have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Android Studio and I just added the play service library and worked.

In Android Studio is:

File -> Project Structure -> in app -> Dependencies

you add clicking in the green + and picking the "com.android.android.gms"